# CSS popup is not scrollable

Tags: css, scrollview

I have a popup on click of submit. But it is not scrollable. I have tried with overflow and overflow-y:scroll. But didnt work. Please let me know if there is any other approach.

Comment: For `overflow-y` to work you need to specify a `height` of the container. It just doesn't scroll automatically. Also, in the future, please post code that you have attempted to write and have tried/tested.

Comment: we need more code/context to help you solve this problem, as the problem source can be vast....